# Is there a standard format for email addresses in MIME messages?

Tags: email, header, mime

When I get an email, there is a header `From:` in the actual MIME message that specifies who the sender of the email is.

I notice that the format of that particular header is sometimes:

> From: user@domain.com

or

> From: Human Readable Name <user@domain.com>

Are these the *only* ways that standard clients format the `From:` header? Or are there others I should be aware of?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are documented in [RFC 5321](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321) and [RFC 5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322).

And you may also be interested in [RFC 2047](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2047).